# Installing Chrome on Raspbian

Tags: raspbian, software-installation, chromium, chrome-os

I am following a tutorial that is based on a Chrome extension so I have to install Chrome. When I tried the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install chromium
```

I get the following error:

```
E: Package 'chromium' has no installation candidate.
```

I understand that it could be an architecture problem but what is the solution in my case?
I am using a `Raspberry Pi 2 Model B`.

```
sudo apt-get install chromium-browser
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package chromium-browser is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'chromium-browser' has no installation candidate
```

The same goes when trying to install chromium. Also I get this when pressing tab:

```
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ sudo apt-get install chro
chromium-bsu        chromium-l10n       chrootuid
chromium-bsu-data   chronicle           
chromium-inspector  chrony
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use these commands to install chromium-browser on Jessie (not Wheezy):

```
wget https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/87113035/chromium-browser-l10n_45.0.2454.85-0ubuntu0.15.04.1.1181_all.deb
wget https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/87113035/chromium-browser_45.0.2454.85-0ubuntu0.15.04.1.1181_armhf.deb
wget https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/87113035/chromium-codecs-ffmpeg-extra_45.0.2454.85-0ubuntu0.15.04.1.1181_armhf.deb
sudo dpkg -i chromium-codecs-ffmpeg-extra_45.0.2454.85-0ubuntu0.15.04.1.1181_armhf.deb
sudo dpkg -i chromium-browser-l10n_45.0.2454.85-0ubuntu0.15.04.1.1181_all.deb chromium-browser_45.0.2454.85-0ubuntu0.15.04.1.1181_armhf.deb
```

^answer is from @dfaze comment's link

Comment: Is there any updated version available?

Comment: I would recommend to use a more official source.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this.. I have been trying to install chromium a lot of time without success. It's even more faster than Epiphany browser. Far more faster.

Comment: @fabrosell I agree for me duck duck go default browser is Jessie was so slow that I did all my best to find a way to install Chromium. It might not sound official but it works. I have done it various times and never failed.

Comment: Glad it was helpful :)

Comment: Check @tyrell-van-den-heever answer it installs the latest version of chromium instead of the old 45 version.

Comment: @czerasz - I agree, but what official source is out there?  I haven't found one.

Comment: @KenWilliams please see my [answer below](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/51602/26875).

Answer (score 12):

Try `sudo apt-get install chromium-browser`

Comment: not working. Can you please take a look at the updated question?

Comment: Welcome to Raspberry Pi! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, it would be preferable to include some explanation here, e.g. what do these commands do? (It was automatically flagged as *low quality* due to its length.)

Comment: @aaron you might wanna add my answer to your tutorial for those who are using Jessie

Comment: As of September 2016 chromium-browser (Chromium 51) is available through the standard Jessie distribution.

Comment: As of August 2017, chromium-browser package on raspbian Stretch matches the latest available version (Chromium 60)

Answer (score 9):

For the `Raspberry Pi Model 3` with `Raspbian Jessie`, copy and paste these 5 lines individually into the terminal:

```
sudo apt-get update
wget -qO - http://bintray.com/user/downloadSubjectPublicKey?username=bintray | sudo apt-key add -
echo "deb http://dl.bintray.com/kusti8/chromium-rpi jessie main" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install chromium-browser
```

Comment: This should be the "correct" answer, because it installs the latest chromium version.

Comment: used this on debian stretch, works well too.

Answer (score 4):

This happens when you try to install a package APT doesn't know about. When you add software sources and run `apt-get update`, your system APT database is updated with all the packages on the repositories listed in the software sources list.

Then when you try to install a package, `apt` checks the package name in its database, finds it and checks the name of the repo from where it got it. It then downloads the package from that repo.

It is always useful to run `apt-get update` before doing `apt-get install XXX`, to ensure you get the latest software version that is on repo.

Comment: I did the update and upgrade before running it and still the same error!

Comment: Have you tryed `apt-get install chro` and then press `tab`key? you'll have a list of package starting with that... my rasp find `chromium`, `chromium-browser` ... isn't it the "browser" that you need?

Comment: Pressing tab key doesn't suggest anything

Comment: What do you think could be wrong?

Comment: first make sure that bash-completion is installed:

`sudo apt-get install bash-completion` or maybe `sudo apt-get install --reinstall bash-completion` and watch in your user directory (`/home/pi` by default) if you find a .bashrc file. if not, copy it from `cp /etc/skel/.bashrc ~/`

Comment: so yeah I didn't have .bashrc in home and the last comment helped. but still chromium isn't a choice. Which one should I go with? `pi@raspberrypi ~ $ sudo apt-get install chro
chromium-bsu        chromium-l10n       chrootuid
chromium-bsu-data   chronicle           
chromium-inspector  chrony`

Comment: oh sorry...! i was testing on my Wheezy Rasp... on the Jessie one ... I have the same problem as you...! may try this link : https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=121195 they show how to download the package and install it ;)

Comment: should I add something here? /etc/apt/sources.list  and what should I add?

Comment: You don't need. The link I recommend is not so old and you only have to follow directives in "code section" : wget 3 packages and dpkg (install package) them

Comment: Great, it runs! failing that mark my answer as resolved , Could You please tag a +1 ;) see you

Answer (score 1):

I can confirm that, as of this post, `sudo apt-get install chromium-browser` works on Ubuntu MATE 15.10 on the Raspberry Pi 3.

Answer (score 1):

```
wget http://ports.ubuntu.com/pool/universe/c/chromium-browser/chromium-browser-l10n_48.0.2564.82-0ubuntu0.15.04.1.1193_all.deb
wget http://ports.ubuntu.com/pool/universe/c/chromium-browser/chromium-browser_48.0.2564.82-0ubuntu0.15.04.1.1193_armhf.deb
wget http://ports.ubuntu.com/pool/universe/c/chromium-browser/chromium-codecs-ffmpeg-extra_48.0.2564.82-0ubuntu0.15.04.1.1193_armhf.deb


sudo dpkg -i chromium-codecs-ffmpeg-extra_48.0.2564.82-0ubuntu0.15.04.1.1193_armhf.deb
sudo dpkg -i chromium-browser-l10n_48.0.2564.82-0ubuntu0.15.04.1.1193_all.deb chromium-browser_48.0.2564.82-0ubuntu0.15.04.1.1193_armhf.deb
```

All credits go [here](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/five-tips-for-getting-the-most-out-of-a-raspberry-pi-3-as-a-pc/).

---

Ansible version:

```
- hosts: all
  vars:
    chromium_version: 48.0.2564.82
    ubuntu_version: 15.04.1.1193
  tasks:
    # --- Install Chromium Browser ---
    - name: Download chromium packages
      get_url:
        url: "http://ports.ubuntu.com/pool/universe/c/chromium-browser/{{ item }}"
        dest: /home/pi/Downloads/
        owner: pi
        group: pi
      with_items:
        - "chromium-codecs-ffmpeg-extra_{{ chromium_version }}-0ubuntu0.{{ ubuntu_version }}_armhf.deb"
        - "chromium-browser_{{ chromium_version }}-0ubuntu0.{{ ubuntu_version }}_armhf.deb"
        - "chromium-browser-l10n_{{ chromium_version }}-0ubuntu0.{{ ubuntu_version }}_all.deb"

    - name: Install chromium packages
      apt:
        deb: "/home/pi/Downloads/{{ item }}"
      with_items:
        - "chromium-codecs-ffmpeg-extra_{{ chromium_version }}-0ubuntu0.{{ ubuntu_version }}_armhf.deb"
        - "chromium-browser_{{ chromium_version }}-0ubuntu0.{{ ubuntu_version }}_armhf.deb"
        - "chromium-browser-l10n_{{ chromium_version }}-0ubuntu0.{{ ubuntu_version }}_all.deb"
    # --- END: Install Chromium Browser ---
```

Find a project integration [here](https://github.com/Advertile/office-monitoring/blob/master/provisioners/ansible/setup-playbook.yml#L34-L58).

> **NOTE**
>   
> I would strongly encourage to add a checksum check (not present in the Ansible version as well) since the files are downloaded over `http`.

Comment: links are dead :(

Comment: http://ports.ubuntu.com/pool/universe/c/chromium-browser/chromium-browser-l10n_64.0.3282.167-0ubuntu1_all.deb --
http://ports.ubuntu.com/pool/universe/c/chromium-browser/chromium-browser_64.0.3282.167-0ubuntu1_armhf.deb --
http://ports.ubuntu.com/pool/universe/c/chromium-browser/chromium-codecs-ffmpeg-extra_64.0.3282.167-0ubuntu1_armhf.deb