# How do i install Chromium on a Pi Zero?

Tags: raspbian, chromium

Google Docs is not supported by whatever browser Raspbian comes with, so I attempted to download Chrome following information from [this question](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/41603/installing-chrome-on-raspbian), but when I followed the link suggested, it said it only works on a Pi 2 which I do not have. How can I download Chromium on a Pi Zero?

```
uname -a
```

returns

```
 Linux raspberrypi 4.1.17+ #838 Tue Feb 9 12:57:10 GMT 2016 armv6l  GNU/Linux
```

Comment: Have you tried `iceweasel`?  I haven't w/ google docs, but it is essentially firefox rebranded (because the source code is open but the ff logo is not, [or something like that](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mozilla_software_rebranded_by_Debian#Iceweasel)).  So if gd works on ff, it should on iceweasel.

Comment: thank you! it's working well though it seems a little slower.

Comment: Did you try it on your Zero anyway?