# Installing Google Chrome

Tags: web-browsers, google-chrome

I have just got a Raspberry Pi and I want Google Chrome on it. I've downloaded the Chrome file from the [Google download page](https://www.google.com/chrome/browser/desktop/index.html?hl=en&brand=CHNG&utm_source=en-hpp&utm_medium=hpp&utm_campaign=en), but I don't know how to open it.

I have no clue about how Raspberry Pis work or how to do anything more complicated than pushing buttons.

Comment: Somewhat related: http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/41603/19949

Comment: What OS are you running?

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is that you can't install Google Chrome. We have a [blog post](https://raspberrypise.tumblr.com/post/140986024839/installing-applications-on-a-raspberry-pi-running) that goes into depth about the topic in general. The gist of it is that Google Chrome isn't offered for `ARM` processors.

Chromium can be installed on a Raspberry Pi 2 or 3, though it isn't the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

Regardless of what everyone else says it is possible to install google chrome and all other x86 apps on raspberry pi! Here is a simple instruction on how to install and run Google Chrome on your RPi 3 device.

***Configure Raspbian***

1.) Google Chrome is CPU intensive application, therefore, we recommend to increase swap space. Open configuration file in Terminal (command line) using the following command:

```
$ sudo nano /etc/dphys-swapfile
```

Raspbian has 100MB of swap by default. You should change it to **2000MB** in the configuration file. So you will have to find this line:

```
CONF_SWAPSIZE=100
```

And then change it into:

```
CONF_SWAPSIZE=2048
```

Press **F3 key** to save changes and **F2** to close the file. **Then restart dphys-swapfile to apply changes:**

```
$ sudo /etc/init.d/dphys-swapfile stop
```

**Then:**

```
$ sudo /etc/init.d/dphys-swapfile start
```

***Install ExaGear Desktop***

2.) Download ExaGear Desktop archive with installation packages and license key. Unpack the downloaded archive by entering the following command in Terminal:

```
$ tar -xvzpf exagear-desktop-rpi3.tar.gz
```

3.) Install and activate ExaGear on your RPi by running install-exagear.sh script in a directory with deb packages and one license key:

```
$ sudo ./install-exagear.sh
```

***Launch Guest X86 System***

4.) Enter the guest x86 system by using the following command:

```
$ exagear
```

**Then:**

```
Starting the shell in the guest image /opt/exagear/images/debian-8
```

5.) Now you are in the x86 environment that can be checked by running the ‘arch’ command:

```
$ arch
```

**Then:**

```
i686
```

6.) It is recommended to update apt-get repositories on the first launch of the guest system:

```
$ sudo apt-get update
```

***Install Chrome***

7.) Download Google Chrome:
Use These Cammands:

```
$ wget http://mirror.retrosnub.co.uk/apt/google/pool/main/g/google-chrome-stable/google-chrome-stable_48.0.2564.116-1_i386.deb
```

8.) Install Chrome:

```
$ sudo dpkg -i google-chrome-stable_48.0.2564.116-1_i386.deb
```

**Then:**

```
$ sudo apt-get install -f
```

***Run Chrome***
[image: Screenshot of chrome]

Answer (score 0):

Best to use Iceweasel... It's basically Firefox.  In my experience it works well.

To install: `sudo apt-get install iceweasel`